# Constructor argument gets lost when passed to super constructor

Tags: java, generics, gwt, constructor, nested-generics

In my GWT app I have a datatype (intended for building and tracking hierarchies of like objects) that extends a superclass, which in turn extends another, abstract superclass. There is a generic parameter declared in the abstract class which is then specified by each subclass as the type of itself. The structure is as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractFoo<T extends AbstractFoo> {
     protected T parent;

     protected AbstractFoo(T parent){
          if (parent != null) parent.addChild(this);
          this.parent = parent;
     }
     //...
}

public class Foo<T extends Foo> extends AbstractFoo<T> {
     public Foo(T parent){
          super(parent);
          //...
     }
}

public class SpecialFoo<T extends SpecialFoo> extends Foo<T> {
     public SpecialFoo(T parent){
          super(parent);
          //...
     }
}
```

When I pass a parent argument to the constructor of SpecialFoo, the constructor of Foo will be called as a superconstructor, and that constructor will in turn call the constructor of AbstractFoo as a superconstructor.

The problem I have is that the parent argument gets reset to NULL when passed from Foo to AbstractFoo. I have no idea why this happens. Can anyone tell me what I need to do in order to pass it through to the abstract base class unharmed?

---

**EDIT:**
I think I've solved it... The trick seems to be that I have to declare the parent argument in each subclass, so that there is a more specific reference to it, like so:

```
 public abstract class AbstractFoo<T extends AbstractFoo> {
      protected T parent;

      protected AbstractFoo(T parent){
           if (parent != null) parent.addChild(this);
           this.parent = parent;
      }
      //...
 }

 public class Foo<T extends Foo> extends AbstractFoo<T> {
      protected T parent;

      public Foo(T parent){
           super(parent);
           //...
      }
 }

 public class SpecialFoo<T extends SpecialFoo> extends Foo<T> {
      private SpecialFoo parent;

      public SpecialFoo(T parent){
           super(parent);
           //...
      }
 }
```

Comment: Seems very unlikely to me. Please show a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Review these points:

1. Prove POSITIVELY that you are receiving a `null` argument in the constructor (print it);
2. Check for **other constructors** in your classes. You may be calling a constructor you are not expecting to call, especially due to the generic type of that argument.

Comment: The argument is definitely not null when I pass it in, and null when it arrives in the base constructor. Also, none of the three classes in question have any other constructor in the code.

Comment: By what means did you ascertain that? It is preferable if you can show the code that prints those results. Define `static T spy(T x) { System.out.println("x = " + x); return x; }` and call it in the `super` calls, as well as in the base class constructor.

Comment: By logging the value of parent to the GWT development mode console.

Comment: Your method of logging doesn't seem to work because T can't be referenced in a non-static context in the abstract class

Comment: Wait -- you are not running this as Java, but compiling into Javascript, and then running that? That would change everything.

Comment: As for my spy, try adding <T>: `static <T> T spy(T x) { System.out.println("x = " + x); return x; }` or just use Object and downcast where needed.

Comment: Yes, it's a GWT app, not plain Java. Sorry.

Comment: Then I withdraw my categorical statement that this cannot possibly be happening. I have no idea what kind of bugs might happen inside GWT.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your parent is **non** `null` you give your SpecialFoo constructor?

Comment: When I'm debugging, the parent is not null in the SpecialFoo constructor and in the Foo constructor, but it is indeed null in the AbstractFoo constructor.

Comment: So then please try to write the smallest possible example causing the problem. You may find the problem yourself while melting your code down.